# how to change file access permissions using .net 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-1.1

I want to change remote file access permissions using .net 1.1. I know in .net 2.0 onward we can use `

> **FileSystemAccessRule**

`but i want to achieve this in .net 1.1. For managing remote file access permissions i am  mapping network drive using win32 API`**

> **WNetAddConnection2**

remote file means it is in same domain but on other machine. I want to remove some permission for the local user of remote machine on which file exists. I found some links which suggest `.net 1.1 doen't include managing ACE so i need to use win32 APIs. If there are some APIs for managing access permission then how can i use it in C#. some links will be helpful.

Comment: If the class you need access does not exist in .NET 1.1 then your only choice is to use .NET 2.0 furthermore .NET 1.1 isn't even supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @Ramhound: I know class is not there in .net 1.1 but can we use if any  win32 api available for this with Pinoke ?

Comment: Yes...You can.  Would of course just be easier to just use a supported version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Ramhound:Problem is i dont know which win32 apis available for access request.

Comment: All the information you need is on the Microsoft website.